# vector<int> pushback causes runtime error?

Tags: c++, compilation, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

For some reason, if I don't have a certain line commented out my code doesn't work.

Here are my three files: Maze.hpp, Kruskal.cpp, main.cpp,

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class KruskalGenerator{
    private:
        void GetNextDirection();
    public:
};
```

```
#include "Maze.hpp"

void KruskalGenerator::GetNextDirection(){
    vector<int> pIndex = {};

    pIndex.push_back(1); // <----- This for some goddamn reason causes runtime error
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Maze.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    //Maze picture = Maze{10};
    KruskalGenerator kSolver;
    //kSolver.Reset(picture);

    cout << "X\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If I don't compile the code with that line commented out `pIndex.push_back(i)` in Generators/Kruskal.cpp then running the executable does not return "X" as it should. Otherwise, if I do comment it out then it prints X just fine. Why could compiling that uncommented code specifically cause a run time error?

I was originally working with a vector of pairs when I found this issue, but I realized something was horribly wrong when even a vector of integers wasn't behaving. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried forcing the version with `--std=c++17`, and even different warning flags. Nothing. Not even a "Segmentation fault" response from running the executable, even though that error is the only one I know which is similar to this type of empty response.

Edit:
Running it in gdb gives me a `During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139` error code.
It could be related to an environment variable issue, but I've raised MinGw bin to the highest in my path, so I'm not sure if it's that.
I'm on GCC version 12.1.0 if that helps anyone.

Also of note is that my other projects compile and run fine, except for this one.

Comment: You might try to compile with sanitizers enabled, something can be smashing the memory reserved for the vector.

Comment: Your code has  undefined behaviour. As always with undefined behaviour the location of the crash does not have to be the same as the location of the error. Often, as in this case, there's no obvious logic to the issue. It's just one of the difficulties of programming in C++.

Comment: `//ommitted for space/clarity` leaving out details is not for clarity. Please read about [mcve]. You can leave out code that is not ncessary to reproduce the issue, but the code you posted does not compile, hence does not produce a runtime error

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I've reduced it now to the minimum. Please try it again.

Comment: In the code you've shown how is `GetNextDirection` called?

Comment: @RetiredNinja It's not called at all, but compiling the code with it commented doesn't cause the issue.

Comment: This is what I pieced together from what is shown: https://godbolt.org/z/xY4551er9 It does not cause a runtime error, and there's no reason it should.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It appears that I am apparently missing a DLL on windows. I will proceed to investigate this.

Comment: sorry, you misunderstood. It was not too much code, but too little. You reduced it to some minimum that does not have the issue. Instead you should try to create an exmple that others can compile and run to see the same runtime error you see.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number For me that is such a minimum that it still has the same issue. The problem for now seems to be the lack of a DLL file. Which is why other can it fine, but I can't.

Comment: Searching for "gdb 0xc0000139" produces many suggestions. Perhaps one applies to your situation.

Comment: [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from SysInternals may help to narrow things down. It is odd that other projects built with the same toolchain don't have the issue, Hope you're successful in narrowing it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that there were two DLLs on my machine. One was old and outdated, the other new and updated. Windows was defaulting to the old one, so I overwrote that DLL with the new one.

A better solution was most likely to simply delete the old DLL that way it wouldn't conflict, but since for some reason the old one was packaged with Git and I rely on Git a lot I didn't want to break anything.